# Filter MongoDb collection if field array and argument array intersect

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, filtering, intersection

I'm creating a Meteor learning project. There is a collection in it, its documents have a property named *keywords* which is an array of strings. I have a second array of strings. I want to filter the collection that way, that it returned only those documents which *keywords* array intersect with that second array, i.e. both arrays have one or several same elements. Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, a query would be:

```
var searchKeywords = ['a','b','c','d']

MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');

MyCollection.insert({
  keywords: ['x','y','a','b']
});
// returns some ID

MyCollection.findOne({
  keywords: { $in: searchKeywords } 
})._id
// returns the same ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really works. Only _searchKeywords_ mustn't be put into the curly braces because $in demands an array.

Comment: Aoff, yes, fixed that! Thanks

Comment: Here is a link to the relevant documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the--in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array